# Where to place landing pages or files inside wordpress?

Tags: content

We have some content that it's outside the wordpress instalation like landing pages, or forms which sometimes must be embedded.

I'm wondering where to place them so I don't loose it if I update the wordpress installation or change the theme.

I thought about placing it on the wp-content folder, is it a good idea? If not where should I place them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them either in an individual folder **next to** `/wp-content` etc., or put the folder **inside** `/wp-content`. You won't lose the files either way.

Core updates take place in `/wp-admin` and/or `/wp-includes` only.